# Can anyone help me identify this font? It has a weird Q

Tags: font-identification

Can anyone help me identify this font? I already tried with WhatTheFont!, Identifont, Fontspring Matcherator. The fonts they suggested are [Eurostile Next Extended](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/eurostile-next/extended-regular?SiteId=15) and many variations of Microgramma Extended but none has the same Q as the image. Any suggestion? I only have the plain png, nothing else.

[image: Logo]

---

The Q was probably altered for personalization purposes.

Comment: Not a font expert, but IMHO the Q clashes with the rest. If this is a logo the Q could have been altered for some purpose (graphical effect or else).

Comment: @xenoid yep, after reviewing more fonts, I also think that's gotta be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Seems to be a logo. Here the bottom is your PNG, on the top is the same text as written.See the specs in Ai's Character panel. In the middle the text is modified. The receipe:

- outline
- add a slight stroke to get heavier glyphs
- squeeze vertically
- fine tune the spaces between the characters
- edit Q

The used font Waukegan LDO Bold is from Fontzillion.

Comment: wow. Thanks a lot! Did you knew the font beforehand or did you use a font identification tool? Just curious, I'm in awe :o

Comment: @oquiroz used fontsquirrel's matcherator, the non-fitting Q was removed from your PNG, special attention to E when watching the results. Never noticed that font before.